# Using column index in data.table condition

Tags: r, data.table

```
dt <- data.table(id=c(8,5,4,9,2,7), col1=c(2,1,2,2,3,1), col2=c(1,1,1,2,3,1))

   id col1 col2
1:  8    2    1
2:  5    1    1
3:  4    2    1
4:  9    2    2
5:  2    3    3
6:  7    1    1
```

I want to subset `dt` to get only rows that contain the value `2` in any of `col1` or `col2` , using column indices rather than names.

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm interested in situations where only column indices are known (names are unknown).

Comment: like `dt[col1 %in% 2 | col2 %in% 2,]` ?

Comment: no, like this `dt[as.vector(dt[,2,with=F] == 2) | as.vector(dt[,3,with=F] == 2)]`, but I have a large number of columns so it is impractical to copy-paste the same condition and change the column index.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `.SD` and `.SDcols`:

```
dt[dt[, Reduce("|", lapply(.SD, function(x) x==2)), .SDcols=2:3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[rowSums(dt[,grep('col',names(dt)), with=F]==2)!=0,]
   id col1 col2
1:  8    2    1
2:  4    2    1
3:  9    2    2
```

With column indices:

```
dt[rowSums(dt[,c(2,3), with=F]==2)!=0,]
```

Comment: this still uses the column names

Comment: I would rather exclude `id` column then compare with 2, in case there are zillion columns.

Comment: `dt[rowSums(dt[,2:3, with=F]==2)!=0,]` is an index-based solution.

Comment: @Orion, here you go.

Comment: `dt[rowSums(dt[,grep('col',names(dt)), with=F]==2)!=0,]` is useful when a column names contain the string `col`, but stills depends on the column name.

Comment: 'dt[rowSums(dt[,-1, with=F]==2)!=0,]` include all but the first column, but my columns could have any positions among other non-relevant columns.

Comment: how do you indentify the columns the columns? by pattern? by a vector giving you the index? by a vector of columns to exclude? In all cases, you just need to replace this in the line of code I provide, which is not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
> dt <- data.table(id=c(8,5,4,9,2,7), col1=c(2,1,2,2,3,1), col2=c(1,1,1,2,3,1))
> dt[dt[[2]] == 2 | dt[[3]] == 2]
   id col1 col2
1:  8    2    1
2:  4    2    1
3:  9    2    2
```