# Select rows with at least one (any) negative value

Tags: r, data.table, subset, data-manipulation

I am looking to create a new data.table that contains all rows with at least one negative value.

Here is a simple reproducible datatable:

```
dt <- data.table(
  ID = c(42, 43, 44),
  Stage_1 = c(-6, 7, 4),
  Stage_2 = c(-15, 4, -8),
  Stage_3 = c(-20, 2, -5)
)

#    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
# 1: 42      -6     -15     -20 # <~~ row to be selected (> 0 negative values)
# 2: 43       7       4       2
# 3: 44       4      -8      -5 # <~~ row to be selected (> 0 negative values)
```

My desired output would be:

```
dt2 <- data.table(
  ID = c(42, 44),
  Stage_1 = c(-6, 4),
  Stage_2 = c(-15, -8),
  Stage_3 = c(-20, -5)
)

#    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
# 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
# 2: 44       4      -8      -5
```

ID 44 for example, has two negative values but I would like to include all of their rows from the main datatable. Basically all rows with a negative value in *any* of their columns I would like to add to a new datatable that contains all their information.

The actual dataset I'm working with has ~50 stage columns, so the most efficient solution is what I'm after.

Comment: Another possibility: `dt[dt[ , do.call(pmin, .SD) < 0, .SDcols = -1]]`, the idea described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885147/efficient-row-wise-operations-on-a-data-table/34019591#comment18073746_7887030)

Comment: There's also `Reduce("|", lapply(.SD,` as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37567937/1851712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt[Stage_1 < 0 | Stage_2 < 0 | Stage_3 < 0]

#    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
# 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
# 2: 44       4      -8      -5
```

**Edit after OP's clarification:**

With many columns:

```
# Find all the rows with at least one negative in each column
rowsDT <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) which(x < 0)), .SDcols = -'ID']
# Reduce to a vector by applying union
rows <- Reduce(union, rowsDT)
# Extract from the main data.table
dt[rows]
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've included this in my original question, but I'd like to avoid this kind of syntax because the actual dataset I'm working with has about ~50 stage columns

Comment: Roger that. I updated the answer accordingly. Not sure if this is the most efficient, but it should work relatively fast.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(
  ID = c(42, 43, 44),
  Stage_1 = c(-6, 7, 4),
  Stage_2 = c(-15, 4, -8),
  Stage_3 = c(-20, 2, -5)
)

dt
#>    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
#> 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
#> 2: 43       7       4       2
#> 3: 44       4      -8      -5
```

- with `apply()` function:

```
dt[apply(dt[, -'ID'], 1, min) < 0, ]
#>    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
#> 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
#> 2: 44       4      -8      -5
```

- with `rowMeans()` function based on the fact that average of a boolean vector with at least one true value is always greater than zero (thanks to @utubun):

```
dt[rowMeans(dt[, -'ID'] < 0) > 0, ]
#>    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
#> 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
#> 2: 44       4      -8      -5
```

- and also with the `rowMins()` function of the [`fBasics`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/fBasics/fBasics.pdf) package:

```
dt[fBasics::rowMins(dt[, -'ID']) < 0, ]
#>    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
#> 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
#> 2: 44       4      -8      -5

# Created on 2021-02-19 by the reprex package (v0.3.0.9001)
```

(Related to [Equivalent to rowMeans() for min()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338517/equivalent-to-rowmeans-for-min))

Regards,

Comment: This is a really efficient way  to execute the code! To avoid changing the code if the amount of columns change in the future I would add `nrow(dt)` to the function. According to this: `dt[apply(dt[,2:nrow(dt)], 1, min) < 0,]`

Comment: Thank you for the improvement. I modify the message.

Comment: Is it me, or actually you meant `dt[, 2:ncol(dt)]`? It works because it is squared data, but otherwise it won't work properly.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, thank you very much. I correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. @utubun thanks for checking

Comment: Yes, instead of `apply()` you can use `rowMeans()` just based on the fact, that average of a boolean vector with at least one true value is always greater than zero, which results in `dt[rowMeans(dt[, -'ID'] < 0) > 0, ]`

Comment: Thank you for the solution with rowMeans(). I added it to the message. I kept also the solution with apply() because I think it can help to understand. I also replaced `2:ncol(dt)` by `-'ID'` in the solution with apply.

Comment: I updated the response with fBasics::rowMins() function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is really good style, but as a shorthand you can use this:

```
dt[ dt[, any(.SD < 0), by = ID][['V1']], ]

#    ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
# 1: 42      -6     -15     -20
# 2: 44       4      -8      -5
```

---

¹However, if `ID` is not unique, it can produce unexpected results.

Comment: `ID` could be replaced by `list(rownames(dt))` to have unique identifier.

Comment: Wanted to keep it short. But yes, since there's no need of `ID` in subsetting call, there is a way around.  I wonder how profiling would look like for all of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `sign` + `rowSums`

```
> dt[, .SD[rowSums(sign(.SD)) < length(.SD)], ID]
   ID Stage_1 Stage_2 Stage_3
1: 42      -6     -15     -20
2: 44       4      -8      -5
```